# How to assign class method to class attribute?

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to assign class methods to class attribute, so I can call the methods from string. When using the class I want to call it from string like:

```
A.MAP['add'](x, y)
A.MAP['subtract'](x, y)
```

This is my current code:

```
class A:
    MAP = {
        'add' : A.add(x, y),
        'subtract' : A.subtract(x, y),
    }

    @classmethod
    def add(cls, x, y)
        return x + y

    @classmethod
    def subtract(cls, x, y)
        return x - y
```

However the result shown error that `A is not defined` at the line of assigning `A.add` to `MAP['add']`. For short functions I can use `lambda`. However, in case of a longer function, how can I achieve this design?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do that? The desired api you've presented is just as unintuitive as it can be, and that takes something. Why do you need, what seems to be a stand-alone methods, as class methods anyway?

Comment: `'add' : lambda x,y: A.add(x, y),`...?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul About the main goal, I would like to process a few methods which can be done from text file instruction. About class methods ,actually it doesn't need to be a classmethod. I just want that to have namespace in front of it so I can easily remember them, but it isn't necessary.

Comment: If you need dynamic access to the class's methods, you can just use `method_name = 'add'; getattr(A, method_name)(3, 7)`. There's no need for you to keep an explicit dictionary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python

Comment: @Cthulhu each function have many line of code. so I can't use lambda

Comment: If you want namespace in front of it then spread the functions across multiple python files, then you have pretty fomrat lile `math.subtract(x,y)`

Comment: @chepner the problem seem to be answer by getattr as shown in previous questions you state. However, the main problem here is the design which I would like to make it appear in dict so I can be easily to understand and read code. I think this question isn't similar as you said.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul you are right there are predefined methods to do this, however I assume this is a learning exercise in OOP programming. Please enforce standardized Python approach as this helps uniformity and readability.

Comment: @Warosaurus just because there are classes doesn't mean that it's oop, and this "excercise" doesn't teach anything good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when you try:

```
class A:
    MAP = {
        'add' : A.add(x, y),
        'subtract' : A.subtract(x, y),
    }
```

you are trying to access e.g. `A.add` before the name `A` exists (the class isn't bound to the name until definition completes) and before the name `add` exists (you haven't defined that method yet). Everything at the top level of the class definition is done **in order**.

---

You need to put the class methods into the dictionary **after** the class has been defined (they don't become callable until definition is complete):

```
class A:

    MAP = {}

    @classmethod
    def add(cls, x, y):  # note colon
        return x + y

    @classmethod
    def subtract(cls, x, y):  # also here
        return x - y

A.MAP['add'] = A.add
A.MAP['subtract'] = A.subtract
```

Note that, as neither class method *uses* `cls`, you could make them `@staticmethod`s instead. Or just use functions - Python isn't Java, you don't need to put *everything* into a class.

---

Alternatively, you can use `getattr` to access attributes (including class methods) by name:

```
>>> class A:

        @classmethod
        def add(cls, x, y):
            return x + y

        @classmethod
        def subtract(cls, x, y):
            return x - y


>>> getattr(A, 'add')(1, 2)
3
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and multiple solution. This help me a lot to understand why A is not define error shown.
getattr isn't solve my problem since one operation require more than one function to handle it. so i need same keyword 'add' to operate multiple function depend on the cases.
I can use @staticmethod by declaring 'add' : add.__func__
however, I think your suggestion to put it after the class is quite easier for me to read. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not program in python like that, instead use a more standard oop approach like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class A:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y

    @classmethod
    def subtract(self, x, y):
        return x - y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
    print a.add(1,2)  # ans: 3
    print a.subtract(2,1) # ans: 1
```

Comment: This doesn't help the OP access the functionality *"from text file instruction"*...

Comment: @jonrsharpe you might be right, honestly I didn't read the question all to much as this is simple exercise. However I suggest you instead stick to a "better" approach and teach others the "right" way to do things rather than crawl for points on SO.

Comment: Note that my answer includes an explanation of the actual problem and various options to help the user resolve it without making too many assumptions about why they're trying to achieve it; there are plenty of legitimate reasons to want to call things by name. If you have a problem with it, downvote it, but it's not like I've told the OP to use `exec`/`eval`. Hop off your high horse and [be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).